# Get child element from the json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the below json, trying the parse the json using javscript.

```js
var data = '{"Req":{"Header":{"tid":"1"},"Body":{"item":{"doReq":{"Header":{"id":"00"},"Body":{"test":[{"req":"000"},{"test2":"0000"}]},"temp":{"temp":"098"}}}}}}';
var json = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(json.Req.Body.item.Body);
```

if we use console.log(json.Req.Body.item.doReq.Body); i will get it, can we able get with out doReq.
Here i want get element without **doReq**, i need get direct Body. Any help.

Comment: This works for me: `json.Req.Body.item.doReq.Body`.

I'm not sure what you mean you want to get the element without **doReq**.

Comment: yes that works me also, but here doReq will change dynamically

Comment: i need inside Body, Body should not change

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't know what your issue is. Please provide a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need dynamic values between `item` and `Body`, you can use this:

```js
    var data = '{"Req":{"Header":{"tid":"1"},"Body":{"item":{"doReq":{"Header":{"id":"00"},"Body":{"test":[{"req":"000"},{"test2":"0000"}]},"temp":{"temp":"098"}}}}}}';
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    
    for (var key in json.Req.Body.item) {
       console.log(json.Req.Body.item[key].Body);
    }
```